# I'm trying to make my basics strong with data structures and linked lists, I keep facing this error

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Here is the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class Linked List:
    def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data
       self.head = None

    def print_list(self):
        cur_node = self.head
        
        while cur_node:
            print(cur_node.data)
            cur_node = cur_node.next

    def append(self, data):
        self.data = data
        new_node = Node(data, next)
    
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
    
        last_node = self.head
        while last_node:
            last_node = last_node.next
            last_node.next = new_node
```

I call it as below:

```
lst=Linked List()
lst.append("A")
lst.append("B")
lst.print_list()
```

The error i get is:

```
C:\Users\vaish\PycharmProjects\hello\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/vaish/PycharmProjects/hello/hackerrank.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vaish/PycharmProjects/hello/hackerrank.py", line 202, in <module>
    llist=LinkedList()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any corrections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Linked list implementation has some bugs. I have comment the code where you need changes

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data): # do not pass next here
        self.data = data       
        self.next = None      # new node should have next=None by default


class Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):    # no need to pass data here, pass data in append function
       self.head = None    # self.head is our head of linked list

    def print_list(self):
        cur_node = self.head
        
        while cur_node:
            print(cur_node.data)
            cur_node = cur_node.next

    def append(self, data):
        #self.data = data        
        new_node = Node(data)     # data will be assigned to the newley created node automatically
    
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return
    
        last_node = self.head
        while last_node.next:     # you have get the last node 
            last_node = last_node.next
        last_node.next = new_node   # this should come outside of the while loop 
                                    #set next of last node as newly created node
lst=Linked_List()
lst.append("a")
lst.append("b")
lst.append("c")
lst.print_list()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @saurabh Sisodia for taking time from your schedule for correcting me. It really worked. Can I have your email ID, please? So that I can get in touch with you, want you to guide me through the errors which I'll be facing in the future.

Comment: I am happy to help you. Please contact me on ssisodia507@gmail.com. And please accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your Linked List Constructor is a parameterized one  def **init**(self, data):

So python expects the value of data when you create Linked List using this lst=Linked List().

Just provide some data there, it will work.

eg.
lst=Linked List("A")